BLE on android cannot call onCharacteristicChanged()
I'm tring to develope a demo of bel communication
BLE server runs on a linux board with BT module, the server is developed with python-dbus, and the part of Characteristic is shown as below
class DapUsrInfoCharacteristic(bluetooth_gatt.Characteristic):
    bonded = False
    def __init__(self, bus, index, service):
        bluetooth_gatt.Characteristic.__init__(
                self, bus, index,
                bluetooth_constants.DAP_CHR_UUID,
                ['read', 'write', 'notify'],
                service)
                # ['encrypt-authenticated-read', 'encrypt-authenticated-write', 
                #  'notify'],
                # service)

    def ReadValue(self, options):
        # Replace this with the actual value to be read
        show_log(LOG_LEVEL.INFO, "Reading value from client")
        return dbus.ByteArray([0x01])
    
    def WriteValue(self, value, options):
        # self.do_notify(value)
        self.callback(CallbackType.BLE_RECVD_MSG, value)
        # self.parse_msg_from_client(value)
    
    def StartNotify(self):
        show_log(LOG_LEVEL.INFO, "starting notifications")
        self.notifying = True

    def StopNotify(self):
        show_log(LOG_LEVEL.INFO, "stopping notifications")
        self.notifying = False

    def register_callback(self, callback):
        self.callback = callback

    def do_notify(self, value):
        self.StartNotify()
        if not self.notifying:
            show_log(LOG_LEVEL.INFO, "Not notifying")
            return
        show_log(LOG_LEVEL.INFO, f"Sending message to client: {value}")
        
        self.PropertiesChanged(bluetooth_constants.GATT_CHARACTERISTIC_INTERFACE, {'Value': value}, [])
        show_log(LOG_LEVEL.INFO, f"Message sent to client: {value}")

    def parse_msg_from_client(self, value):
        msg_type = int(value[0])
        if msg_type == BLE_MSG_TYPE.BONDED.value:
            self.bonded = bool(value[1])
            show_log(LOG_LEVEL.INFO, f"Bond status: {self.bonded}")
            self.callback(CallbackType.BLE_BONDED, None)
        else:
            show_log(LOG_LEVEL.INFO, f"Unknown message type: {value}")

BLE client is a Android phone, I can read and write value of the characteristic on the BLE server. However, It does not work when I want to subscribe the notification for the characteristic, the most related part code of Android is shown as below:
/* Gatt call back */
private BluetoothGattCallback gattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
        ...

        @Override
        public void onDescriptorWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor, int status) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Descriptor write status: " + status);
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Descriptor written");
                mainHandler.post(() ->  eventSink.success("Descriptor written"));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
            Log.d(TAG, "------------------");
            byte[] value = characteristic.getValue();
            Log.d(TAG, "Characteristic changed: " + Arrays.toString(value));
            mainHandler.post(() ->  eventSink.success("Characteristic changed: " + Arrays.toString(value) + "\n"));
        }
    };

/*Enable characteristic notification*/
boolean isEnableNotification =  bluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(targetCharacteristic, true);
if (!isEnableNotification) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Failed to enable notification");
                    return;
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "Characteristic notification enabled");

                List<BluetoothGattDescriptor> descriptors = targetCharacteristic.getDescriptors();
                Log.d(TAG,"Total descriptors: " + descriptors.size());
                for (BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor : descriptors) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Descriptor: " + descriptor.getUuid().toString());
                    descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
                    descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_INDICATION_VALUE);
                    boolean isWriteDesp = bluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
                    Log.d(TAG, "Descriptor write status: " + isWriteDesp);
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "Finished writing descriptors");        

Could you plz give some advice? Thanks very much!
Could you plz give some advice? Thanks very much!

Try to writeDescriptor after you setCharacteristicNotification and choose the UUID you want to subscribe, for example:
val descriptor: BluetoothGattDescriptor =
                characteristic.getDescriptor(convertFromInteger(0x2902))

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
    descriptor.value = BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE
    gatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor)
} else
    gatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor, BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_INDICATION_VALUE)

